# CSV encoding inside input text file step on Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am doing i simple input text file into Kettle Pentaho PDI 8.1.0. The file has several acceding char like "á" and it is a .csv file.

In the settings of the input text file step i set the encoding to ISO-8859-1. So when i go to "Show file content" button everything are correct.

But when i press the Preview rows so i can see the data separated into columns then i get error on all acceding chars and are replaced with ? So Mária becomes M�ria.

By using the word error i do not mean that kettle does not run the transformation but that the data are not correct.

Any Idea?

Comment: provide me the sample data.
attach sample data file.

Comment: i can not provide sample data but it is normal data with special chars like what i am writing above. so i am loosing the characters

Answer (score 0):

Your file is obviously not encoded in ISO-8859-1.

The Encoding field in the Content tab of 'Text file input' is used by the "Preview rows" button but not by the "Show file content" button.

Try another encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding cp866, hope it helps, or also you could try encoding with latin-1